# While loop skips user input

Tags: java

I'm trying to keep a scanner command  in a while loop until the user gives good input. If I run the following, it keeps looping through without waiting for input if I get the input wrong first (but waits for the first input). Why is that?

```
while (true){ 
    System.out.println("Enter temperature in Fahrenheit: ");
    try {
        x = in.nextFloat();
        break;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid temperature!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to see more code.  Maybe a complete running solution as we cannot tell what `in` does.    Also, the continue isn't needed there.  The behavior is the same without it.

Comment: @just_a_programmer safe to assume that `in` is a `Scanner`... because of the `.nextFloat()` method. Make sure you're calling `.nextLine()` after `.nextFloat()` to **consume the newline character**.

Comment: Try adding in.nextLine() in the try-catch block.

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
    while (true){ 
        System.out.println("Enter temperature in Fahrenheit: ");
        try {
            x = Float.parseFloat(in.nextLine());
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid temperature!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> When a scanner throws an InputMismatchException, the scanner will not
>   pass the token that caused the exception, so that it may be retrieved
>   or skipped via some other method.

per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

It's rereading the same token over and over, continually trying to convert it to a float and failing.

You need to consume that token inside the exception handler, so that the next iteration of the loop will block waiting for more input.

Comment: Perhaps also suggest how he could avoid this problem